# How do we get from Fethiye/Dalaman to Cappadocia by bus?

Tags: buses, turkey, cappadocia

We are planning a holiday to Turkey starting in Fethiye then going via Cappadocia to Istanbul. I am trying to find out how to get from Fethiye to Cappadocia. We do not mind stopping for a few days on the way at some interesting places.

---

Possible options I have thought of:

- 2 nights in Pamukkale then via Konya etc.
- Head up the coast to Side, spending a few days getting there, then bus via Konya maybe stopping at Eskil.

Both options with or without a Gulet trip of a few days between Fethiye and Olympos.

(My wife likes the sea and we are going for a holiday not to “tick off” as many sites as possible. As it is a short holiday of only three weeks we can’t fit everything in and relax.  Hence not taking an organised couch tip.)

Comment: Do you have relatives or friends in Eskil? Otherwise there is no (touristic) reason to stay there.

Comment: @MarcelC. I thought Lake Tuz was rather nice, but reading up on it more, it does not seem to be worth the effort.

Comment: It's indeed not worth the stop. Anyway you can get a glimpse from the bus when going from konya to nevshehir. That should be enough.

Answer (score 7):

Nice! I have done a similar trip 5 years ago.

From Fethiye to Nevşehir is at least 13 hours by bus. If there are direct buses they are not very frequent. Anyway, it makes sense to split the trip!

We went from Nevşehir to Fethiye via Konya and Antalya. To give you an order of magnitude of the legs:

- Fethiye - Antalya: 3 hours
- Antalya - Konya: 6 hours
- Konya - Nevşehir: 4 hours

You can of course only make one stop in Konya or Antalya. That's up to you. You should also be aware of the fact that there are two routes from Fethiye to Antalya. One along the coast and one inside the country. The latter is much faster! Along the coast takes 6 to 7 hours. It is a scenic but very shaky route.

I had to plan the stop in Antalya as part of a compromise with my better half. I would have preferred to stop over in Konya and [Eğirdir](http://www.turkeytravelplanner.com/go/Aegean/Egirdir/index.html), rather than Anatalya. But that's life ;-) Eğirdir is really a nice place. Everybody who has been there seems to like it.

If ever you are in a hurry, and you only want to see Fethiye, Cappadocia and Istanbul, without stopovers, I would do it it the following order: Fethiye - Istanbul - Nevshehir. From the point of view of bus transport it is easier to plan and to handle. This being said, there are also interesting stopovers along the latter journey!

The coaches to the Cappadocian villages transit through Nevşehir. From there you will be transferred to whatever your final destination in Cappadocia. That's why I am talking about Nevşehir.

If you have trouble to find a direct bus to Nevşehir you can also try to find a bus to Kayseri or Aksaray, as a plan B. These cities are really nearby and you have frequent buses to the Cappadocian villages (via Nevşehir).

UPDATE:

Although I think that Pamukkale has a limited interest, the two options you have added make sense too. Now you have to play and pick the "best" option.

Answer (score 4):

There are buses referred to in a similar question on [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g293969-i367-k5573539-Night_Bus_Fethiye_to_Goreme_Cappadocia-Turkey.html).  I've looked at [site the answer referred to](http://www.tokatyildizi.com.tr/) and there is a bus from Fethiye to Goreme, which leaves at 16:00 and arrives there about 4:00, which seems to be the only one I could find.

Once you are in Goreme, you might find a few [other bus lines](http://www.ticketlineturkey.com/index.php/bus-companies-in-turkey.html) to take you around and [to Istanbul](http://wikitravel.org/en/G%C3%B6reme) but I wasn't able to find online reservations for some of them.

Comment: Goreme to Istanbul is no problem, there are a 101 buses, however we are lickly to stop over for 2 days in Ankara to break the trip and see the sights.

Comment: Goreme/Nevshehir to Ankara is not a problem either. There is a fair number of busses each day. It is sufficient to buy a ticket once you arrive in Cappadocia. Ankara to Istanbul is like taking the metro. Walk to the station, buy a ticket and leave within shortly.